# login to obiee and execute SQL using python

Tags: python, pyodbc, cx-oracle, obiee

I've tried various ways of extracting reports from Oracle Business Intelligence (not hosted locally, version 11g), and the best I've come up with so far is the pyobiee library here, which is pretty good: https://github.com/kazei92/pyobiee.  I've managed to login and extract reports that I've already written, but in an ideal world I would be able to interrogate the SQL directly.  I've tried this using the executeSQL function in pyobiee, but I can only manage to extract a column or two and then it can't do any more.  I think I'm limited by my understanding of the SQL syntax which is not a familiar one (it's more logical, no GROUP BY requirement), and I can't find a decent summary of how to use it.  Where I have found summaries, I've followed them and it doesn't work (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIESQ/toc.htm#BIESQ102).  Please can you advise where I can find a better summary of the logical SQL syntax?  The other possibility is that there is something wrong with the pyobiee library (hasn't been maintained since August).  I would be open to using pyodbc or cx_Oracle instead, but I can't work out how to login using these routes.  Please can you advise?

The reason I'm taking this route is because my organisation has mapping tables that are not held in obiee and there is no prospect of getting them in there.  So I'm working on extracting using python so that I can add the mapping tables in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to rethink what you are doing. First of all the python is a wrapper around the OBI web services which in itself isn't wrong, but an additional layer of abstraction which hides most of the web services and functionalities. There are way more than three...
Second - the real question is "What exactly are you trying top achieve?". If you simply want data from the OBI server, then you can just as well get that over ODBC. No need for 50 additional technologies in the middle.
As far as LSQL is concerned: Yes, there is a reference: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIESQ/BIESQ.pdf
BUT you will definitely need to know what you want to access since what's governing things is the RPD. A metadata layer. Not a database.

Comment: How would I go about using ODBC to get it?  Bearing in mind that I've stated this is not a locally hosted server

Comment: You need an ODBC connection: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEIT/odbc_data_source.htm#BIEIT535